# Web.py SQL queries giving odd data

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, web.py

I have been developing a small application in Python using the Web.py framework that does some simple PostgreSQL queries. I have noticed that the returned value contains a whole bunch of stuff which encapsulates the actual raw data.

The following code is supposed to query the value of `name` from the table `todo`

```
name = db.query("SELECT name FROM todo;")
```

but when I call...

```
return name[0]
```

The following is returned/printed...

```
<Storage {'name': u'Learn web.py'}>
```

The data is correct, the value is "Learn web.py", but I was wondering if it was possible to just get the raw data, "Learn web.py" instead of all the other stuff. I could parse it, but I was wondering if there was a more correct way like `name.rawdata()` function that I am missing? I have tried `name[1]` which is "out-of-bounds".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
name[0].name
```

The `[0]` selects the first row from the result. The `.name` gets the `name` column from the row.

Additionally, rather than using `db.query` with a raw SQL string, I'd use `db.select`:

```
names = db.select('todo', what='name')
```

See [the documentation](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api#web.db) for more information.

Comment: THANK YOU. I've been trying to figure this out for ages, and nobody had been able to give me an answer. You have no idea how happy I am right now.